# Typeahead example in Angular sends empty parameter to BackEnd

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to adapt the following example [link](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage#type-ahead-suggestions) to my angular frontend application.

It should fire a get request to my backend with the search parameter from an input field. It always fires the GET call to my backend after typing, but the parameter is always an empty string..

Below my code:

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    searchBox = null;
    autoComplete = null;

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.searchBox = document.getElementById('searchBox');

        this.autoComplete = fromEvent(this.searchBox, 'input').pipe(
          map((e: KeyboardEvent) => (<HTMLTextAreaElement>e.target).value),
          filter(text => text.length > 2),
          debounceTime(250),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          switchMap(s => this.apiService.autoComplete(s))
        );
    }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="searchBox">

  <pre>
    {{autoComplete | async | json}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

api.service.ts:

```
export class ApiService {
     autoComplete(s: string): Observable<KeyNames[]> {
        const params = new HttpParams();
        params.append('search', s);

        return this.httpClient.get<KeyNames[]>(this.API_URL + '/tags/autoComplete', {params})
          .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('autoComplete', []))
          );
      }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my autoComplete() function always gets called with an empty string?

Comment: Can you show ``this.apiService.autoComplete`` method? By the way it's ``HTMLInputElement`` not ``HTMLTextAreaElement``.

Comment: added code snippet from apiService

Comment: What happens when you subscribe to ``this.autoComplete``?

Comment: well, I subscribe to `autocomplete` in the html file using async pipe operator. Value stays null because my BackEnd returns null if an empty string is sent

Comment: there are so many autoComplete tutorials out there, they all work for me to call my backend after typing but it always sends an empty string..

Comment: that's strange...I created sample with your code but changed api call to some observable with delay to simulate http call and it works properly.

Comment: for explanaition:
1. map() => gets the value from the input html element
2. switchmap() => take the value from above and initiate the api call

Am I right?

Comment: in general yes but it does not initiate the api call - the async pipe initiate it since it subscribe to this.

Comment: I tried to debug with breakpoints in Webstorm but I couldn't do it for observables.

Comment: could you post your sample code or send me pm?

Comment: if you put simple console log at the beginning of the ``autoComplete`` method what does it output?

Comment: great idea. we're getting closer step by step. The input parameter in autocomplete has the right value when logging it to console

Comment: so there must be an error in my autoComplete method from apiService

Comment: you can additionally check in browser console(network tab) if request has this param with correct value - and if it does it something wrong on backend side.

Comment: the parameter is always missing in the GET request.
It should look like `.../autoComplete?search=ABC` although it is always only `.../autoComplete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is probably with `append` method because it returns `HttpParams` it could means that you should do:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('search', s);
```

or simply:

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('search', s);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Debugging with console.log() helped a lot :)